# Why was Jericho Cancelled and is there any way to know the missing episodes' story?

Tags: cancellation, jericho

I have just finished watching season 1 of Jericho and while looking at season two I noticed that it cuts half way through, I'm presuming it was cancelled.

Can someone please shed some light on why it was cancelled as I was really enjoying it and also will there be any way for me to find out what should have happened after the cut off point.

P.S. I wish that the companies making the show would just release the rest on DVD if they can't carry on with it being broadcast.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree!

It was cancelled due to the lack of support of the show. The second season is still a "complete" season, it just wraps things up pretty quickly.

If you're still interested in what happens after season two there is apparently a comic that came out to continue the story where it was left off. (Not sure if its fan made or fan supported or made by the creators.)

[Jericho comic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jericho_Season_3%3a_Civil_War)

It was meant to be cancelled after season 1 but after a large amount of people were upset they gave season two a try to revive it and it apparently failed.

Comment from one of my questions about Jericho:

> The reason for the rushed ending was that the show was actually
>   cancelled after the first season due to poor ratings. However, it was
>   a cult hit and a number of fans protested the network to get another
>   season commissioned. This happened; it got another 7 episodes. But it
>   got cancelled again after the second season, hence why it all got
>   wrapped up prematurely and so many corners were cut.

–  Craig Russell

Another comment from my question:

> Not sure, however, you may be interested in checking out the Jericho
>   comic. It picks up as a comic book version of season 3. So, if you're
>   a Jericho fan and interested in finding out more about what happens,
>   I'd look into this. As a note, although I do have the comic, I haven't
>   read it yet so I honestly don't know how good it is!

–  Ashlinry

Answer (score 3):

Only seven episodes were ordered for the short second season. There were two endings filmed: the one that aired had an emotional conclusion and many of the fans were satisfied with that.

The alternate ending, available in full on the 2nd season DVD, was the original ending that led into season 3.

The Jericho comics/graphic novels continue the story from the aired ending:

http://tinyurl.com/JerichoS3Novel
Season 3 gives us the backstory of John Smith, the mastermind of the attacks, and we get to meet Johnston's brother (who looks a lot like Johnston).

http://tinyurl.com/S4Jericho
Season 4 has a double agent living in Jericho and the country grows closer to a civil war.

Season 5 has been approved and is being worked on.

In the meantime, there are still hints of a continuation. The latest being a movie made by CBS Films and co-financed by Netflix.

You can read the latest Jericho news on [Saving Jericho](http://www.savingjericho.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Jericho simply did not live up to expectations. First season of any new show buys its way to life via high ratings and a strong character development. Now Jericho, to say the least failed to do so regardless of the fact that their take on post apocalyptic society looked very promising.

Answer (score -3):

Tech movies like these, in order to be successful, can not have any major screw ups in the plot.

Where Jericho failed was on the idea of the bomb being the "smoking" gun.

New York did not blow up. The government had captured that bomb. You can tell the writers were forced to "wrap it up".

Getting the bomb to Texas provided no more info than what could have been revealed by the captured New York bomb.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV SE.  While this may be the right answer, for it to be accepted, you should have a link of some sort, to sort of prove that this is the right answer.  It helps the original poster, and helps future people who might have the same question.